# Regression line, prediction and confidence intervals in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, intervals, lm

I would like to ask you, please, how to create from the [table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GOfZ37iUf2UDDYV-PlvkROTbyPmOS2sM/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106449091870021727609&rtpof=true&sd=true) two statistical graphs:

1. regression line with prediction interval
2. regression line with  confidence interval

U used this script but I don't know what to do next:

```
pred <- lm(dta$Number.of.species ~ dta$Latitude)
pred_interval <- predict(lm(dta$Number.of.species ~ dta$Latitude), level = .99, interval = "confidence")[,2]
conf_interval <- predict(pred, newdata=dta, interval="prediction")[,3]
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(
  dta$Latitude, 
  dta$Number.of.species, 
  pch = 1, 
  ylim = c(0, 180), 
  xlim = c(37, 40)
  )


plot(
  dta$Latitude, 
  dta$Number.of.species, 
  pch = 1, 
  ylim = c(0, 180), 
  xlim = c(37, 40)
) 

abline(pred)
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just learning R, I would make 2 recommendations.

First, I would suggest learning the *ggplot2* package, rather than using the base R plotting system. It is generally much easier to build up complex plots with many parts using `ggplot()`.

Second, there are several packages designed to make working with model results easier in R. The most prominent of these are *broom* and the *easystats* collection of packages (*modelbased*, *performance*, *parameters*, etc.). Between the two, I would recommend *easystats*.

I'll demonstrate how to build up the data frame for plotting the model manually and using *modelbased*.

### Manually building data frame

```r
library(ggplot2)

# fit the model
m <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)

# construct prediction and confidence intervals using predict()
m_ci <- predict(m, interval = "confidence") |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  setNames(c("fit", "ci_lo", "ci_hi"))
m_pi <- predict(m, interval = "prediction") |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  setNames(c("fit", "pi_lo", "pi_hi"))
#> Warning in predict.lm(m, interval = "prediction"): predictions on current data refer to _future_ responses

# merge the interval data frames with the data frame used in the model
m_data <- 
  merge(
    merge(
      model.frame(m), m_ci, by = "row.names"
    ),
    m_pi
  )

# make a plot using the merged model data frame
ggplot(m_data) + # use m_data in the plot
  aes(x = disp) + # put the 'disp' variable on the x axis
  geom_point(aes(y = mpg)) + # add points, put the 'mpg' variable on the y axis for these
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = pi_lo, ymax = pi_hi), fill = "lightblue", alpha = .4) + # add a ribbon for the prediction interval, put the pi_lo/pi_hi values on the y axis for this, color it lightblue and make it semitransparent
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = ci_lo, ymax = ci_hi), fill = "lightblue", alpha = .4) + # add a ribbon for the confidence interval, put the ci_lo/ci_hi values on the y axis for this, color it lightblue and make it semitransparent
  geom_line(aes(y = fit)) + # add a line for the fitted values, put the 'fit' values on the y axis
  theme_minimal() # use a white background for the plot
```

[image]

### Using the *modelbased* package to streamline some of the above steps

```r
library(modelbased)

# compute intervals, including fitted values and original model matrix
ci <- estimate_expectation(m) # model fitted values and confidence intervals (uncertainty intervals on the expected values/predicted means)
pi <- estimate_prediction(m) # model fitted values and prediction intervals (uncertainty intervals on the individual predictions) 

plot(ci) + # this produces a ggplot with points, fitted line, and confidence ribbon
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = disp, ymin = CI_low, ymax = CI_high), data = pi, alpha = .4) + # add a prediction ribbon
  theme_minimal() # use a white background
```

[image]

Here is how to modify the color of the ribbon when working with *modelbased*:

```r
plot(ci, ribbon = list(fill = "lightblue")) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = disp, ymin = CI_low, ymax = CI_high), data = pi, fill = "lightblue", alpha = .4) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Dear Brenton, thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately I need to do it in a basic plot function.
In the task, I have to make 4 plots: 
1)just the points with data
2) data with linear regression line
and these two which I had to ask for help. So now, when I have the first two in the basic plot and these two from you in ggplot, I don't know how to combine.

Thank you very much for your time and help.